# KeystoneJs 2-relationship field to same model with depend on each other

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

Suppose I have model Job which holds 2 field ref to primary_skills and secondary_skills

```
primary_skills: {type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Skill', many: true},
secondary_skills: {type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Skill', many: true},
```

How can i make a dependency to not show up in secondary_skills those that already chosen as primary_skills??

Comment: KeystoneJS "relationships" are really just based on mongoose models. Therefore "arrays of ObjectId" containing the same `_id` reference value of the other collection. There is no such thing as a "constraint" here. All you can do it actually make sure your code does not make the same entry in both arrays. Usually with `$pull` from one array as you `$push` to the other. Ideally you would instead use [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) for this instead of two arrays though.

Comment: Try having a look at Keystone.js relationship filters.